# dissecting the og module - where is the content type form submit handler for function og_ui_form_node_type_form_alter?

Tags: nodes, organic-groups, forms

drupal version: 7

Hi, I'm trying to add settings to a content type form and I'm using organic groups as a guide. I see the form elements for OG being added in the og_ui.module at line 316 in this function `og_ui_form_node_type_form_alter` but I don't see where these form elements are being submitted, handled, saved, processed... I would've expected it to add another submit handler to the form but it doesn't seem to be the case. Anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Wrong place, main things happen on og.module.

Comment: right, I figured the `og_group_type_(node_type)` variable would be set in the main module but I don't see where. How is the info from that form being processed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens automatically.

Adding a variable to that form means that it is automatically saved with `variable_set()` with a `_node_type` suffix. Similar to admin forms.

Here is another example: [userpoints_nc_visits_form_node_type_form_alter()](http://api.worldempire.ch/api/userpoints/userpoints_nc-7.x-1.x--userpoints_nc_visits--userpoints_nc_visits.module/function/userpoints_nc_visits_form_node_type_form_alter/7-1).

As you can see, the form element is for example named `userpoints_nc_visits_points` and the default value is fetched with `userpoints_nc_visits_points_type` (inside the get setting api function).